# VideoDisplay not playing video in assets for iPad AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, mxml

I'm not able to play any video (.flv or .mp4) in the `VideoDisplay` tag for an iPad Application in AIR.

I'm using `spark:VideoDisplay`. I can play videos if I provide a full path. But I want this app to be deployed on an iPad. How can I do this?

Comment: "You can play ideos if you provide full path."  What does this mean?  What is your path?  Is this in an emulator or on an android device or some other way?  What is the path you use to deploy the video to the app on an iPad?  Why is it different than the path that works?

Comment: It's worth noting that standard h.264 videos generally do not play back using VideoDisplay on iOS. For a streaming app I had to build, the only way I could get them to playback was by using `StageWebView` or `StageVideo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your videos embed with your application. please follow this for e.g you video  located at assets/videos/ipad.flv

You need to point out application directory (deployed location) like

```
var videoURL:String = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/videos/ipad.flv").nativePath;
```

Note that nativePath works with iPad application for point out assets (if not working try with url sometimes it works).